# How to create a function for each filtered interval in data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains a column of total ads shown to a consumer, and also a binary column that shows whether they bought the product or not.

I want to calculate the conversion rate (# of People bought/# People in Group) after grouping the consumers based on the number of ads they have seen (e.g. Group 1: 0-9 ads, Group 2: 10-19 ads etc. all the way until say 300).

Is there a way to do this other than manually calculating by group (i.e doing 30 of the same calculation)? Perhaps with some sort of looping function?

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Check out `dplyr` functions: `group_by` & `summarise`